# MembershipProvider validation fails after password change

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlmembershipprovider

I am using an SQLMemberShipProvider.

When I enter my username and password the following code is executed `membershipProvider.ValidateUser(myUserName, myPassword)` and returns `true` indicating that the user is valid.

I reset the password with the following code:

```
var username = membershipProvider.GetUser(myUserName, false);
username.ChangePassword(username.ResetPassword(), newPassword);
```

Now when I enter my username and the new changed password, the following executes again `membershipProvider.ValidateUser(myUserName, newPassword)`, but this time the validation fails.

I don't understand this, as I am using the same provider for both calls of `ValidateUser`. The password seemed to have changed as the original password is no longer valid as well.

The password format is hashed, IsLocked is false and IsApproved is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks good. This is occuring most porbably because resetPassword is not set to true in your web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
  <providers>
    <add name="SqlProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="SqlServices"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
      passwordFormat="Hashed"
      applicationName="MyApplication" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Ensure that enablePasswordReset="true" is set.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, enablePasswordReset is set to true

Comment: This was a PEBKAC issue, the new password I used did not conform to the password regex as set out in the provider, so validation failed. Changing this password to something that does satisfy the Regex, works as expected.